# Class has no field or association named user.email when using CallbackFilter to search multiple submodel fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin, dql

I am using Sonata Admin to manage my Order entities. Each Order has a User, and each User has an email, a firstname and a lastname, all of which are strings.

After following the instructions [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_list.html#callback-filter), I find that the list view for my Orders shows up with a nice filter. But when I try to run the filter, I get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 72 near 'email LIKE '%sally%'': Error:
>   Class App\Entity\Order has no field or association named user.email

The documentation page has this tantalizing teaser on it:

> TODO: * basic filter configuration and options * targeting submodel
>   fields using dot-separated notation * advanced filter options
>   (global_search)

... but I can't seem to quite figure out how to make that dot notation work for me.

**How should I set up my query in OrderAdmin.php?**

Here's the relevant part of Order.php:

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="orders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

... and the relevant part of User.php:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Email(groups={"Import"})
 * @Groups({"api_read", "api_write"})
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @Groups({"api_read", "api_write"})
 */
protected $firstname;

/**
 * @Groups({"api_read", "api_write"})
 */
protected $lastname;
```

... and here's the relevant part of OrderAdmin.php:

```
/**
 * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
 */
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('user', CallbackFilter::class, [
        'show_filter' => true,
        'callback' => [$this, 'getFullUserNameFilter']
    ]);
}

public function getFullUserNameFilter($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
{
    if (!$value['value']) {
        return;
    }

    $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like($alias.'.user.email', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%')),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like($alias.'.user.firstname', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%')),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like($alias.'.user.lastname', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%'))
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching my previous approach and using a left join. So my getFullUserNameFilter method now looks like this:

```
public function getFullUserNameFilter($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value)
{
    if (!$value['value']) {
        return;
    }

    if(is_string($value['value'])) {
        $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.%s', $alias, $field), 'user');
    }
    $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like('user.email', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%')),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like('user.firstname', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%')),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->like('user.lastname', $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('%' . $value['value'] . '%'))
    ));
}
```

(Everything else from my example code remains the same.)

Now the filter works great.